# Invertir filas a columnas con SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

necesito realizar un select que muestre de una tabla las filas como columnas, usando el lenguaje SQL es decir

-- Tabla

```
DESC | ENERO | MARZO | JUNIO

A    |  80   |   73  |   84  
B    |  100  |  100  |  100
```

Lo que necesito es que me muestre la consulta

```
DESC |   A   |   B   |

ENERO|  80   |  100  |   
MARZO|  73   |  100  |  
JUNIO|  84   |  100  |
```

Comment: Esta pregunta en Stackoverflow en inglés justo resuelve tu duda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

Hay unas cuantas maneras de hacerlo. Pero en todos los casos, se asume que se conoce de antemano cuáles son las columnas que quieres convertir a filas (`ENERO`, `MARZO`, `JUNIO`), y cuáles (y cuantos) son los valores en la columna `DESC` que quieres convertir a columnas (`A`, `B`). Si tu deseo es que todo esto sea dinámico, no creo que sea posible con una simple consulta SQL.

La primera etapa es convertir:

```
DESC | ENERO | MARZO | JUNIO

A    |  80   |   73  |   84  
B    |  100  |  100  |  100
```

al resultado intermediario siguiente:

```
DESC |  MES  | VALOR

A    | ENERO |  80
A    | MARZO |  73
A    | JUNIO |  84
B    | ENERO |  100
B    | MARZO |  100
B    | JUNIO |  100
```

Una buena manera de lograrlo en PostgreSQL es usando la función [`UNNEST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html):

```
select t."desc", u.*
  from tabla t
  cross join unnest(
    array['ENERO', 'MARZO', 'JUNIO'], 
    array[t.enero, t.marzo, t.junio]
  ) with ordinality as u(mes, valor, sort_no)
```

Notarás que uso la claúsula [`WITH ORDINALITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) para generar una columna adicional `sort_no` que sirve para controlar el orden lógico de los meses.  De modo que el resultado de la consulta viene siendo:

```
DESC |  MES  | VALOR  | SORT_NO

A    | ENERO |  80    |   1
A    | MARZO |  73    |   2
A    | JUNIO |  84    |   3
B    | ENERO |  100   |   1
B    | MARZO |  100   |   2
B    | JUNIO |  100   |   3
```

Con este resultado intermediario en mano, puedes usar un `GROUP BY` junto con agregación condicional para obtener tu resultado final deseado:

```
with cte as (
    select t."desc", u.*
      from tabla t
      cross join unnest(
        array['ENERO', 'MARZO', 'JUNIO'], 
        array[t.enero, t.marzo, t.junio]
      ) with ordinality as u(mes, valor, sort_no)
)
select mes as "desc",
       max(case when "desc" = 'A' then valor end) as A,
       max(case when "desc" = 'B' then valor end) as B
  from cte
 group by mes, sort_no
 order by sort_no
```

En PostgreSQL, también puedes aprovechar la claúsula [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html) para aplicar la condición en vez de `CASE`, aunque esta última es más estándar:

```
with cte as (
    select t."desc", u.*
      from tabla t
      cross join unnest(
        array['ENERO', 'MARZO', 'JUNIO'], 
        array[t.enero, t.marzo, t.junio]
      ) with ordinality as u(mes, valor, sort_no)
)
select mes as "desc",
       max(valor) filter (where "desc" = 'A') as A,
       max(valor) filter (where "desc" = 'B') as B
  from cte
 group by mes, sort_no
 order by sort_no
```

[**Demostración en vivo**](http://rextester.com/DMRIM25761).

Otra manera de lograr el resultado deseado es usando la función [`CROSSTAB`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html), que es más o menos equivalente a la función `PIVOT` que existe en otras bases de datos:

```
select mes as "desc", a, b
  from crosstab('select u.mes, u.sort_no, t."desc", u.valor
                   from tabla t
                  cross join unnest(
                    array[''ENERO'', ''MARZO'', ''JUNIO''], 
                    array[t.enero, t.marzo, t.junio]
                  ) with ordinality as u(mes, valor, sort_no)
                  order by 1',
                'select * from unnest(array[''A'', ''B''])')
       as ct(mes text, sort_no int, a int, b int)
order by sort_no
```

Toma en cuenta que, para usar la función [`CROSSTAB`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html), debes asegurarte que el módulo [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) esté instalado en tu base de datos. Esta es la sentencia necesaria para instalar el módulo, de ser necesario:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Comment: saludos, estoy buscando la solucion al proceso inverso... seria tan amable de revisar esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170258/relaciones-de-muchos-a-muchos-postgrest-consulta-para-sacar-en-una-sola-fila

Answer (score 0):

**NOTA:**
Tomar en cuenta esta respuesta solo como ejemplo, debido a que el lenguaje requerido es `postgreSQL` y el ejemplo que menciono a continuación aplica para `SQL`, una disculpa por la confusión.

Quieres hacer un pivot, se hace agrupando y con CASE:

```
declare @tabla table(
     [DESC] char,
     ENERO INT,
     MARZO INT,
     JUNIO INT
);

insert into @tabla values ('A',80,73,84);
insert into @tabla values ('B',100,100,100);


select mes,
  sum(case when [desc] = 'A' then value else 0 end) A,
  sum(case when [desc] = 'B' then value else 0 end) B
from
(
  select 1 id, [desc], ENERO value, 'ENERO' mes
  from @tabla
  union all
  select 3 id, [desc], MARZO value, 'MARZO' mes
  from @tabla
  union all
  select 5 id, [desc], JUNIO value, 'JUNIO' mes
  from @tabla
) src
group by id,mes
order by id
```

Esta es la forma de hacerlo "a pie", puedes seguir el ejemplo del link que sugirió @Error404 para hacerlo de forma dinámica o con algunas otras funciones de SQL como pivot.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Comment: Toma en cuenta que la pregunta concierne PostgreSQL, de modo que sería apropiado arreglar el script para que funcione en esa base de datos. Además, el enlace y la información que contiene es para SQL Server, no PostgreSQL.

Comment: @sstan tienes razón, disculpa y no se postgreSQL :-S

Comment: saludos, estoy buscando la solucion al proceso inverso... seria tan amable de revisar esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170258/relaciones-de-muchos-a-muchos-postgrest-consulta-para-sacar-en-una-sola-fila