# Relaciones de muchos a muchos postgrest, consulta para sacar en una sola fila

Tags: postgresql, rendimiento, sql

Tengo una tabla **A**:

```
-----------------------------
| id  |   nombre   |   cel  |
-----------------------------
|1    | Juan       | 1653727|
|2    | Pedro      | 6353526|
|3    | Hernan     | 4465672|
-----------------------------
```

Otra tabla **B**:

```
--------------------
| id  | material   |
--------------------
|1    | lapiz      |
|2    | cuaderno   |
|3    | mochila    |
--------------------
```

Y una tabla intemedia **AB**:

```
-----------------------------
| id_A  | id_B   | cantidad |
-----------------------------
|1      |   1    |    3     |
|1      |   2    |    2     |
|2      |   1    |    2     |
|2      |   2    |    2     |
|3      |   1    |    4     |
|3      |   2    |    1     |
|3      |   3    |    1     |
-----------------------------
```

Y tengo una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT 
   A.nombre nombre, 
   B.material material,
   AB.cantidad cantidad  
FROM AB
INNER JOIN A ON AB.id_A =  A.id
INNER JOIN B ON AB.id_B =  B.id
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

```
----------------------------------
| nombre  | material  | cantidad |
----------------------------------
| Juan    |  lapiz    |    3     |
| Juan    | cuaderno  |    2     |
| Pedro   |  lapiz    |    2     |
| Pedro   | cuaderno  |    2     |
| Hernan  |  lapiz    |    4     |
| Hernan  | cuaderno  |    1     |
| Hernan  | mochila   |    1     |
----------------------------------
```

> EL problema es que tengo los nombres repetidos y no los quiero de esa manera.

**El formato que deseo es el siguiente:**

```
------------------------------------------------
| nombre   | lapiz   |  cuaderno  |   mochila  |
------------------------------------------------
| Juan     |   3     |     2      |     0      |
| Pedro    |   2     |     2      |     0      |
| Hernan   |   4     |     1      |     1      |
------------------------------------------------
```

No se si es posible realizar esto con una consulta, funcion o procedimiento almacenado en `postgres`.

Agradesco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: y si pruebas agregando la condición distinct?

Comment: justo después del select agrega un distinct así SELECT distinct
   A.nombre nombre, 
   B.material material,
   AB.cantidad cantidad  
FROM AB
INNER JOIN A ON AB.id_A =  A.id
INNER JOIN B ON AB.id_B =  B.id

Comment: La principal pregunta es ¿Cuantos "materiales" deseas mostrar en la consulta? ¿Solo tres como el ejemplo?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho,   En todo caso, los tipos de "material" podrán ser elegidos desde el front-end, estos sera en un maximo de 20, el caso es que son tantos datos que hacer la tabla con el lenguaje de programacion `php-laravel` hace que la respuesta sea algo lenta. Por lo cual deseo que este proceso lo realice la base de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, debo decirte que en mi opinión este tipo de consulta debieran resolverse en la vista y no en el motor, pero si aún así necesitas hacerlo, la forma más básica y estándar (salvo por el uso del `coalesce`)  sería hacer un `LEFT JOIN` por cada material. Algo así:

```
SELECT A.nombre,
       coalesce(Lapiz.Cantidad,0)     Lapiz,
       coalesce(Cuaderno.Cantidad,0)  Cuaderno,
       coalesce(Mochila.Cantidad,0)   Mochila
       FROM A
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT AB.id_A, AB.Cantidad
                         FROM AB
                         WHERE id_B = 1 -- Id de Lapiz
            ) Lapiz
            ON Lapiz.id_A = A.id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT AB.id_A, AB.Cantidad
                         FROM AB
                      WHERE id_B = 2 -- Id de cuaderno
            ) Cuaderno
            ON Cuaderno.id_A = A.id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT AB.id_A, AB.Cantidad
                         FROM AB
                         WHERE id_B = 3 -- Id de mochila
            ) Mochila
            ON Mochila.id_A = A.id
;
```

La salida:

```
| nombre | lapiz | cuaderno | mochila |
|--------|-------|----------|---------|
|   Juan |     3 |        2 |       0 |
|  Pedro |     2 |        2 |       0 |
| Hernan |     4 |        1 |       1 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/32f06/16)

Si quisieras "acomodar" 20 materiales en una única consulta deberías construir una consulta similar, con 20 `LEFT JOIN` para cada uno de los materiales seleccionados.

Existe también la posibilidad de usar una función extendida [`crosstab`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) pero no tengo forma de probarlo, por lo que solo te dejo una referencia a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: Gracias, justo estoy leendo sobre `crosstab`, creo que se acomoda de mejor forma a lo que deseo. mil gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, y creo que la consulta se me hara algo larga, pero es muy util, mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega la condición de `DISTINCT` a tu sentencia SQL, la cual se va a encargar de filtrar los datos que se encuentren repetidos; que en este caso es el nombre de la persona

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   A.nombre nombre, 
   B.material material,
   AB.cantidad cantidad  
FROM AB
INNER JOIN A ON AB.id_A =  A.id
INNER JOIN B ON AB.id_B =  B.id
```

> ACTUALIZACIÓN
>
> Debes agregar al final de tu consulta un offset para tener claro el
>   límite de resultados a devolver que en tu caso pudiera quedar de este
>   modo

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   A.nombre nombre, 
   B.material material,
   AB.cantidad cantidad  
FROM AB
INNER JOIN A ON AB.id_A =  A.id
INNER JOIN B ON AB.id_B =  B.id LIMIT 1,3;
```

Que significa devuelveme 3 registros empezando el el registro número 1; la sintáxis ahí esta acortada pero puede quedar de este modo:

```
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 1;
```

es igual a:

```
LIMIT 1, 3;
```

Comment: ya lo intente y solo me muestra los primero datos

Comment: cuales datos te muestra? @Shassain

Comment: @Shassain igual puedes probar con group by y elegir que el campo de agrupamiento sea el nombre y quita lo de distinct

Comment: en la primero el resultado es el mismo, en el segundo me sale error: `Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'ON`

Comment: @Shassain te agregué algo a mi respuesta espero ayude